# Starting a new activity also triggers the onPause method

Tags: android, dynamic, android-activity

I have have a listview which says "details" and when the user clicks one of the item, I'm getting the position of that certain "details" and taking the user to an edit screen with dynamic data loaded to certain variables.

When I start the details activity the logcat tells me that both the details activity and my mainmenu activity were started, which brings my user to the mainmenu. This obviously does not leave anyone happy and I would like to know if anyone can provide me with some help as to why is this happening?

Code:

DetailsButton:

```
    removeLi.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> aV, View v, int pos,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                information.open();
                information.delete(pos + 1);
                information.close();

                rowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                whenAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                postedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                detailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                removeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Dialog sucDeleted = new Dialog(ManageAppointment.this);
                sucDeleted.setTitle("Sucesfully deleted");
                TextView tvDintWorked = new TextView(ManageAppointment.this);
                tvDintWorked.setText("The appointment at position:" + pos
                        + " was sucesfully deleted");
                sucDeleted.setContentView(tvDintWorked);
                sucDeleted.show();

            }
        });
```

The onPause method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Intent main = new Intent("com.DCWebMakers.Vairon.MAINMENU");
    startActivity(main);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onPause() is always called on every activity if another activity is started and replaces it, as specified [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). If you want to override the back button's behavior to start a specific activity, consider overriding the onBackPressed() method, instead of adding your code into onPause().

Answer (score 0):

That's as designed. The `onPause()` method runs every time *another* activity covers the current activity, even if it's your own. See the [activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). The real question is, why are you starting the main activity in `onPause()`?

Comment: I'm using it in case the user hits the back button. But now that you mention it and I'm making some sense of it that's what the back button was made for correct?